# Apache Zeppelin - Set default interpreter

Tags: apache-zeppelin

In Zeppelin, at each row I am having to provide the interpreter at each row. Is there a way to set the interpreter for the whole session.

```
%pyspark 

import re
```

Took 0 seconds.

---

```
import pandas as pd
```

console :1: error: '.' expected but identifier found. import pandas as pd

---

```
%pyspark

import pandas as pd
```

Took 0 seconds.

---

How do I set the interpreter for the whole session?

Answer (score 7):

The Spark Interpreter group currently has 4 interpreter as listed here...

https://zeppelin.incubator.apache.org/docs/0.5.0-incubating/interpreter/spark.html

The default interpreter is `%spark` and default interpreter is selected based on the order of the interpreter listed in the `zeppelin.interpreters` property in **zeppelin-site.xml** config file.

The current order of interpreter in your zeppelin-site.xml (`zeppelin.interpreters` property) will be this ...

```
org.apache.zeppelin.spark.SparkInterpreter,org.apache.zeppelin.spark.PySparkInterpreter
```

Modify this to ...

```
org.apache.zeppelin.spark.PySparkInterpreter, org.apache.zeppelin.spark.SparkInterpreter
```

and restart Zeppelin (`zeppelin-daemon.sh restart`)

This will make `%pyspark` as default interpreter.

Thanks

Comment: Is this still true in Zeppelin 0.6.2? Changed order as you suggested above, but still spark comes first in the list in Interpreter settings in UI, and Spark stays default..

Comment: Any way to do that without modifying any config files?

Answer (score 1):

The above answer did not work on recent Zeppelin versions.

To set the default interpreter, check `/etc/zeppelin/conf/interpreter.json` and look for something like:

```
...
{
  "name": "spark",
  "class": "org.apache.zeppelin.spark.SparkInterpreter",
  "defaultInterpreter": true,
  "editor": {
    "language": "scala",
    "editOnDblClick": false
  }
},
...
{
  "name": "pyspark",
  "class": "org.apache.zeppelin.spark.PySparkInterpreter",
  "defaultInterpreter": false,
  "editor": {
    "language": "python",
    "editOnDblClick": false
  }
}
```

Now everything seems trivial. We just need to change the `defaultInterpreter` of `spark` to `false`, and `defaultInterpreter` of `pyspark` to `true`.

And then restart the zeppelin (`sudo stop zeppelin; sudo start zeppelin`).

Answer (score 0):

Even Fishball's answer for recent Zeppelin seems outdated. My `conf/interpreter.json` came with spark as default (`"defaultInterpreter": true`) and python/pyspark as not (`"defaultInterpreter": false`) and yet Zeppelin picked up python/pyspark as default. And in my case, I wanted spark over pyspark.

The solution was to just drag and drop interpreters in Zeppelin web console's `interpreter binding` section.

Answer (score 0):

change `zeppelin.interpreter.group.default` in `conf/zeppelin-site.xml` from `spark` to whichever interpreter you would like to use.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).