# Making pyspark default in Apache Zeppelin?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-zeppelin

Can't find out how to set PySpark to be the default interpreter for Zeppelin.

I know I can make Spark the default interpreter by putting it at the top of the list.  But having to remember to add %pyspark to the top of each new cell is basically as annoying as adding %spark.pyspark

I'd just use Jupyter, but I'm working off a DC/OS Cluster and Zeppelin was available as a preconfigured app, while Jupyter looks like a bit of an ordeal to install on the cluster.

So, to surmise: Anyone know how to make pyspark the default interpreter for Apache Zeppelin?

Thanks!

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33834401/apache-zeppelin-set-default-interpreter